# For serialization in .NET, should I use JavaScriptSerializer and XmlSerializer or their DataContract counterparts?

Tags: .net, serialization

For serialization on .NET, should I use JavaScriptSerializer and XmlSerializer or their DataContract counterparts (DataContractXmlSerializer and DataContractJsonSerializer)?

**EDIT**

I want to serialize things to store on files, or to send through the internet. I need some flexibility as to how the output will look like sometimes.

Comment: What do you want the outcome to be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using WCF, use DataContract* serializers. Otherwise XmlSerializer is pretty much the .NET standard for generating readable serialization file. JavaScriptSerializer/Json.NET are also very good alternatives for web stuff (i.e. for consuming web services, or posting simple REST queries, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

My default choice would be to use JSON, there would need to be a compelling reason to go beyond that. What are your endpoints? Communication channel? Package size?

If this is this for an ASP.NET application, then JSON is likely your *best* choice. The standard I am using for best is:

- robust serialization capabilities readily built into or available to
  .NET applications
- lightest package load

  and
- easy to understand what is going on