# REST API data contract to support xhtml

Tags: c#, html, xml, json, rest

I am using .NET providing REST API for web application. The client want to show something in a flexible format such that the data coming from server can determine what format to show. For example, 
Category
  This is a test category
  { Section here is where the data determine the format, this can be 2x2 grid, or 3x5 grid }

The data contract currently is `    using System;
    using System.Runtime.Serialization;

```
[DataContract]
public class Category
{
    private readonly string m_description;
    private readonly string m_data;

    public Category(string description, string data)
    {
        m_description = description;
        m_data = data;
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "description")]
    public string Description
    {
        get { return m_description; }
    }

    [DataMember(Name = "data")]
    public string Data
    {
        get { return m_data; }
    }
}`
```

My question is whether this contract can support xhtml or html in the Data field so that the grid format can be serialized to the client?

Comment: Did some search and found a similar question for using WCF, the suggestion there is to use Stream as the type to gain full control of the data format. Not sure if there is similar solution when using ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: possible duplicate of [For serialization in .NET, should I use JavaScriptSerializer and XmlSerializer or their DataContract counterparts?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697560/for-serialization-in-net-should-i-use-javascriptserializer-and-xmlserializer-o)